# React State not being correctly updated inside a socket.io listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

So I'm trying to change a React State inside a socket.io listener using its args.
The problem is when I try to do, it does not show the new updated State.

CODE:

```js
                props.server.on('game status', async args=>{
                    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 250));
                    document.getElementById('instruction').textContent = args['status']

                    await setIsGameReady(args['isReady'])
                    console.log(args['isReady'], isGameReady)
                })
```

This function is inside UseEffect with empty array.

The output is: "true, false" ( args['isReady'], isGameReady)

What I expected was "true, true"

Full Code:

````js
    const serverInteractions = {


        startListeners: ()=>{



            if (props.server.hasListeners('game status')) {} else{
                props.server.on('game status', async args=>{
                    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 250));
                    document.getElementById('instruction').textContent = args['status']

                    await setIsGameReady(args['isReady'])
                    console.log(args['isReady'], isGameReady)
                })

                props.server.on('game result', async args=>{
                    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 250));
                    setGameStep(0)
                })

            }



        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        serverInteractions.startListeners()

    }, []);```
````

Comment: although it's often written that "updating state in React is asynchronous", this isn't strictly true - the `setXXX` functions do NOT return a Promise that you can `await`. When people say this, they just mean you won't be able to observe the change straight away, but at a slightly later moment (in the next render of the component, in fact). So there's likely no problem with your code, just with your expectation of what will be logged.

Comment: also, completely unrelated to the question, but: you really shouldn't be doing direct DOM manipulation (setting the `textContent` of an element here) when you're using React. React provides a much cleaner, declarative, way to change text in response to state changes, and if you try to do both there's a risk that your manual DOM updates will get overwritten by React anyway.

Comment: Your `isGameReady` variable is capture in the handler function, it's not going to change ever. You can use `useRef` instead of `useState` if you want to access latest state